# Symfony 2 bundle name, using short name for class

Tags: symfony

Examples given in Symfony 2 webpage

```
Namespace                       Bundle Class Name
Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle          AcmeBlogBundle
Acme\Bundle\Social\BlogBundle   AcmeSocialBlogBundle
Acme\BlogBundle                 AcmeBlogBundle
```

My vendor name is 9 characters large, but I find it redundant to have `MyVendorName/ForumBundle` and class name `MyVendorNameForumBundle.php` if it resides already in `MyVendorName/ForumBundle` directory.

Will it bring me future problems if I just name my primary class `ForumBundle` supposing I want to share? Obviously, the namespace is still `MyVendorName/ForumBundle`.

Is that class actually used somewhere or is just a one-time config somewhere?

My main concern is that I don't want to use the large name (eg `MyVendorName/MyVendorNameForumBundle::someMethod()`) everytime I need to access it.

Maybe this isn't all correct, I am new to Symfony 2.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Symfony also uses convention over configuration and i am not sure if all scripts work properly if you do that. (e.g. console commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't imagine the namespace `Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle` coming from `AcmeBlogBundle`. Something more appropriate would be `Acme\BlogBundle`, which would make `AcmeBlogBundle`. If you did `Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle`, the class name may actually end up being `AcmeBundleBlogBundle`.

The vendor name is included in the class to prevent conflicts. What if someone else decided to name their bundle class `BlogBundle`?

I also can't imagine you ever calling a method that directly belongs in the root class of a Symfony2 bundle.

Generally, Symfony2 will provide you with shortcuts to get to the most common things you need. For example, when you reference a controller in your `routing.yml`:

```
AcmeSocialBlogBundle:Default:show
```

It will actually resolve to

```
Acme\SocialBlogBundle\Controllers\DefaultController::showAction
```

My suggestion? *Relax.* The Symfony2 dev team has addressed this concern with shortcut notation already. Follow the convention that is generated by the `php app/console generate:bundle` command as a starting point and everything else will fall into place. Here are some valid namespaces:

```
Acme\Plugins\BlogBundle
Acme\BlogBundle
Acme\ClientName\BlogBundle
sjagr\MyAwesomeBundle <-- See how I made my Github username a vendor name?
```

My word of warning is that when you try and go against the grain of a framework's recommendations, you'll revisit that decision later with regret. I have done so, and I'm currently rewriting Symfony2 apps that I wish I had taken the time to do right in the first place.